# How can I get redux-saga to wait for two actions to happen at least once in any order?

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

Redux saga noob here.

I need to create a saga that loads the initial state for the redux store from my API server.

This involves using two async sagas: `getCurrentUser` and `getGroups`.

I need to issue these ajax requests in parallel and wait for the `GET_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS` and `GET_GROUPS_SUCCESS` actions before issuing the `pageReady` action which tells the UI it's time to render the react components.

I came up with a hacky solution:

```
function * loadInitialState () {
  yield fork(getCurrentUser)
  yield fork(getGroups)

  while (true) {
    yield take([
      actions.GET_GROUPS_SUCCESS,
      actions.GET_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS
    ])
    yield take([
      actions.GET_GROUPS_SUCCESS,
      actions.GET_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS
    ])
    yield put(actions.pageReady())
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that if for some reason `GET_GROUPS_SUCCESS` is issued twice, the `pageReady` action will be called to early.

How can I get redux saga to wait for `GET_GROUPS_SUCCESS` and `GET_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS` to happen **at least once in any order**?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you want the [`all` effect](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#alleffects)

```
function * loadInitialState () {
  // start loading state...

  yield all([
    take(actions.GET_GROUPS_SUCCESS)
    take(actions.GET_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS)
  ]);

  yield put(actions.pageReady())
}
```

Comment: How would you do it if **any** of these 2 was required?

Comment: post another question.

Comment: @haxpanel use the race effect instead of all

Comment: You can `const firstAction = yield take([action1, action2])`